# CRM 2013 Quick Campaign shows completed but only part of emails being sent out

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

My environment is CRM 2013 on premise. I'm trying to run a quick campaign under marketing list. There're 13315 members under marketing list. When I run quick campaign, it took over 3 hours to send 4494 successfully and 18 failures. there're still lots not being sent out. but it shows 'Completed' in Status Reason field. It's wired. Do you know why? is there any limitation for members? Here is the screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Similar issue](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/30923) reported but no response.

I can give you troubleshooting steps:

1. Check for any useful errors in platform trace
2. Verify the status of Email activities using Advanced find (pending send?)
3. Identify the recipients (members of Marketing list viz Contact,Account) for ‘Do not Allow emails’ flag

Maybe [helpful](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2579154/quick-campaign-e-mails-are-stuck-in-pending-send-status-in-microsoft-d), Not sure if it’s related to you.